# Body scan guided meditation that covers only the upper body?

Tags: beginner, meditation-mindfulness

I'm not certain if this is the right place to ask this question so let me know if I need to try a different forum.

Does anyone know of a guided body scan that only covers the upper body? My partner is paraplegic and is trying meditation for the first time. It could be really good for her. But the first words were "feel your feet on the floor". She tried to stick with it, but it was just too much. I know meditation sometimes means you sit with discomfort, but that is way too much pain and way too early in her trying meditation.

So, if anybody knows of such a body scan from the waist up - please let me know.

Also

Many thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not heard of a meditation only practice in the upper body. However, breath meditation practice in conjunction with the stomach so they may consider upper body experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the instructions accordingly. A proper body scan just involves probing and examining the kinaesthetic response from every cell your body, not just the skin, but internal organs and everything in between. You don't have to start with the feet or the head, you can start wherever you feel like, can stay as long as you want. But the more you can pervade your awareness to every cell in the body, the better results you're going to get in your meditation practice. The longer you work at it, years and decades, if you're serious about your practice and dedicate several hours a day to it, energy channels will open up and it will feel like you can sense every cell in body, even all of them simultaneously.

Comment: I guess I could record a modified one for her. But, asking a paralyzed person to be aware of their paralyzed parts? That just isn't going to happen. To ask a new meditator to do it? That's just cruel. Internal organs are paralyzed too. It would be like cutting off an able-bodied persons leg, moving it 10 feet away, and asking them to sense every cell in it. I'm sure I don't fully understand it being able-bodied myself, but living with her I've learned that being paralyzed is so much more than just not being to stand up.

Comment: it's not a requirement that one has to produce a tangible sensation upon probing any cell in the body to be considered successful, or doing it 'properly'. One simply has to scan a cell, a small piece of body, and just detect whether there is any sensation there.